# Issue using sed into a loop

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

**Problem Description:**
I am trying to read the file test.csv, and add a variable $lastid (let's say 35 for the example) at the end of each line.
But this variable needs to be incremented every two lines.

**Expectations:**
I am expecting to get:
for line 1 and 2 ",36" at the end of the line.
for line 3-4 ",37" at the end of the line.
for line 5-6 ",38" at the end of the line.
and so on...

**Script Code:**

```
set -x ##debug mode on
lines=$( wc -l < test.csv ) ## you count the total of lines
lines=$((lines+1)) ## you increment it
g=$lastid   ## this is the variable of my lastid_game from my database (let's say 35 for the example)
i=1
j=1
while [ $j -le $lines ] ## while my lines number is lower or equal than the total of lines
do
    if [ $(( $j%2 )) -eq 0 ] ## if my line number is even
    then
        echo "number "$j" is even" ## I display it
        j=$(( $j+1 )) ## I increment my lines
        sed -e "s/$/,$g/" test.csv > test1.csv
    else
        echo "number "$j" is odd" ## I display my line is odd
        g=$(( $g+1 )) ## I increment my id_game
        j=$(( $j+1 )) ## I increment my lines
        sed -e "s/$/,$g/" test.csv > test1.csv
    fi
done
set +x ##debug mode off
```

**Content of test.csv:**

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,b,c,d,e,f
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

**Current Output:** ( which I believe is doing good)

```
++ wc -l
+ lines=46
+ lines=47
+ g=35
+ i=1
+ j=1
+ '[' 1 -le 47 ']'
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'number 1 is odd'
number 1 is odd
+ g=36
+ j=2
+ sed -e 's/$/,36/' test.csv
+ '[' 2 -le 47 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'number 2 is even'
number 2 is even
+ j=3
+ sed -e 's/$/,36/' test.csv
+ '[' 3 -le 47 ']'
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'number 3 is odd'
number 3 is odd
+ g=37
+ j=4
+ sed -e 's/$/,37/' test.csv
+ '[' 4 -le 47 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'number 4 is even'
number 4 is even
+ j=5
+ sed -e 's/$/,37/' test.csv
+ '[' 5 -le 47 ']'
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'number 5 is odd'
number 5 is odd
+ g=38
+ j=6
+ sed -e 's/$/,38/' test.csv
+ '[' 6 -le 47 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'number 6 is even'
number 6 is even
+ j=7
+ sed -e 's/$/,38/' test.csv
+ '[' 7 -le 47 ']'
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'number 7 is odd'
```

**Current Result:**
test1.csv gives me the following result:

```
,59a,b,c,d,e,f
,59a,b,c,d,e,f
,59a,b,c,d,e,f
,59a,b,c,d,e,f
,59a,b,c,d,e,f
,59a,b,c,d,e,f
,59a,b,c,d,e,f
a,b,c,d,e,f,59
```

**Problem 1:** The id is always the same.

**Problem 2:** The id does not get incremented but seems to only display the last one calculated.

Does anyone has an idea what could be possibly wrong please?

Comment: Please post the output you _want_ to have.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Btw.: `>` overwrites a file, `>>` appends to a file.

Comment: Don't use a shell loop for this. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4):

It's typicall to use `awk` to parse files:

```
awk '{print $0 "," 36+int((NR-1)/2)}'
```

- `NR` - current line number, starts with `1`
- `(NR-1)/2` - calculate number from current line number. So a sequence of numbers like: `{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, ....etc.}` for each line number
- `int(...)` - round down to integers
- `36+` you wanted to start with `36`
- `$0` current line
- `","` add a comma between the number and current line

Notes:

- `sed -e "s/$/,$g/" test.csv > test1.csv` is overwriting *the same file* *over and over again* for each loop
- bash has arithmetic expansion, with that you can do `if ((j <= lines)); then` for clearer code.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
val="35"  ##shell variable.
awk -v var="$val" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR%2!=0{++var} {$(NF+1)=var} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v var="$val" '      ##Starting awk program from here and creating awk variable var which has val in it.
BEGIN{                   ##Starting BEGIN section of awk program from here.
  FS=OFS=","             ##Setting field and output field separator as comma here.
}
FNR%2!=0{                ##Checking condition if line is odd line number wise then do following.
  ++var                  ##increase value of var with 1 here.
}
{
  $(NF+1)=var            ##Adding 1 more field which has var field in it for current line.
}
1                        ##1 will print current line here.                        
' Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your feedback. 
It is almost correct (the id is incrementing every two lines, but it inputs it at the beginning of each line, expect the last line which is at the end correctly.

Comment: @CédricDirr, you need to create either a shell variable in your script named `var=35` OR if you don't want to create shell variable then change my awk starting to `awk -v var="35"  .....` and it should fly then, let me know once you check it please.

Comment: It works! my file was on EOL conversion windows in notepad++, not linux. Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
var=36
sed '1{x;s/^/'$var'/;x};                   # prime the counter
     1~2,+1{G;s/\n/,/};                    # append the counter
     2~2{x;s/.*/expr & + 1/e;x}' file      # increment the counter
```

The address range `1~2,+1` means 1 step 2 plus 1 or every two lines starting at line 1.

The address `2~2` means 2 step 2 or every second line starting at 2.

The RHS of the last substitution uses the command `expr` to increment the stored variable by means of the `e` flag which evaluates the expression.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using *GNU* `seq`, `paste`, `wc`, and some shell arithmetic with a
   bit of fudging to make up for [floating point round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error):

   ```
   n=35; seq -f '%.0f' $n.9 .5 $(($n + $(wc -l < test.csv)/2 )).5 | 
   paste -d , test.csv -
   ```
2. Using `jot`, `paste`, & `wc`:

   ```
   n=36 p=$(wc -l < test.csv) ; jot  $p $n $((p+n)) .499999999 |
   paste -d , test.csv -
   ```

Output of either:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,36
a,b,c,d,e,f,36
a,b,c,d,e,f,37
a,b,c,d,e,f,37
a,b,c,d,e,f,38
a,b,c,d,e,f,38
a,b,c,d,e,f,39
a,b,c,d,e,f,39
```